# How can I tell Capybara to find the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a subscription screen in my app. There are 5 different choices, and therefore 5 different buttons. It's data-driven so there could be 1 or 10 or whatever. `n` choices.

In writing a request spec, I find that I do not know how to point to these. I know I can set `match: :first` as an argument to the `click_button` message, but is there another way that I can arbitrarily call one of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara provides an [`all` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method). This method returns an instance of [`Capybara::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Result). This class includes Enumerable and thus provides methods like `#[]`.

`all(selector)[n]` will return n-th element on the page conforming to locator. It will be an instance of [`Capybara::Node::Element`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element) that you can use freely using methods like `click`, `set`, etc.

A disadvantage is that `all` doesn't wait for elements to appear. If you need it, you can use synchronization like:

```
page.should have_css('#id') # wait for some element that appears at the same time or after the element that you click at the next row
all(locator)[n].click
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily you have a couple different options.  You can call by thr nth child, you can do (.class)[2] , or if you're looking for a first, you canme element = first (.css) and then interact with the element bysaying something like element.click.  If you're doing the page object model, you definitely should define your objects anyway